# Moving abroad for few years, maybe working on a start-up - which countries have reasonable costs of living and good IT infrastructure?

Tags: relocation, costs, startups

I'm an IT guy who would like to take some time off work, leave UK (and EU)
and spend some time somewhere else. I'd like to work on my own projects/ideas,
or just work on open source projects and spent time with new / upcoming technologies.

I do not want/expect to work full time for a particular company; I'm happy to cover the entire costs for let's say two years and then see what happens.

An example country is Vietnam - south preferably, which has quite reasonable
costs of living and has decent IT sector/infrastructure (think Flappy Bird). But there is bureaucracy and paperwork, meaning it's not possible to just go and live there (even if you have the funds).

So the question is - what countries are safe, have reasonable cost of living (let's say 2000 USD per month) and a good IT infrastructure (good internet connection, G3/G4 networks etc)?

Comment: I moved to Peru and did just that.  There are several countries in South American(Chile, Peru, Uruguay, Argentina, Panama) that might fit your needs. I ended up opening an office/etc.

Comment: What's "safe"? Each to their own. Some countries have terrible areas, even in relatively safe cities.  There are entire books written on this subject :/  I recommend having a look at the [help] and ideally isolate this to a specific problem.  Also check out expatistan.com - very handy for comparing costs etc.

Answer (score 3):

First, moving abroad is tightly related to visa. This may limit your options very quickly, because unless you have relatives abroad, the main remaining option is to get a work visa, so you have to get sponsored by a company willing to hire you.

With that said, south east Asian could be a good choice indeed. Taiwan and Singapore would be my first choices. Modern countries, safe, with a developing economy, more or less English-speaking people... I may disagree on their political stances (the fight with China for one, the monarchy for the other), but overall, both look to be interesting places, with decent standards of living, and many good opportunities in IT there. The cost of living in Singapore may discourage you though. I don't know how much costs the life in Taiwan.

Hong Kong could be a solution too. As a British citizen, you may find it easier to move there actually. And they still use English as a language to work with, in the administration and international companies.

In Africa, I would mostly consider South Africa and Morocco. South Africa is said to be a beautiful country to visit, has big cities with many IT Companies, and they speak English. Morocco on the other end may be stable enough to live in and has IT companies (often, offshore branches for first world companies).

In South America, I'd recommend Chile. It's safe, vast, with a developing economy. But you'll have to learn Spanish.

Of course, there are always the USA and Canada, and if you stay away from the main cities, you may be able to live comfortably for a decent price. The same with Australia and New Zealand. I assume you considered those countries already.

Finally, Iceland can be interesting, if you consider it to be "out of Europe". They tend to live in autarky since the economic crisis, but there may be opportunities over there.

I hope that helps a little.

Comment: Iceland is expensive, but I would think $2000 USD/month would be enough for ME.  I spent between two and four hundred in two days, but I was staying in a hostel and eating in restaurants.  You can get a cost-of-living estimate customized to your lifestyle at numbeo.com but I have reason to believe I can actually do better than it suggests.

Comment: Chileans tend to find it offensive when people refer to their country as a chili pepper.

Comment: Sorry about that, my mother tongue is French, and we call it Chili. I meant Chile !